# How to dry a lot of module extends

Tags: ruby, module

Currently I have this structure in my code:

```
module Mappers
  extend ActiveSupport::Autoload    
  ...

  module Login
    extend ActiveSupport::Autoload
    ...
  end

  module Admuser
    extend ActiveSupport::Autoload
    ...
  end

  module Admsubdevice
    extend ActiveSupport::Autoload
    ...
  end

  module Admdevice
    extend ActiveSupport::Autoload
    ...
  end
end
```

I have to extend every module to use autoload functionality.

Is there a way to extend modules only once to have this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this solution is more compact:

```
[Mappers, Mappers::Login, Mappers::Admuser, Mappers::Admsubdevice, Mappers::Admdevice].each do |m|
  m.extend ActiveSupport::Autoload
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def module_with_autoload &proc
  Module.new{extend ActiveSupport::Autoload ; proc.call}
end

Mappers = module_with_autoload do
  ...

  Login = module_with_autoload do
    ...
  end

  Admuser = module_with_autoload do
    ...
  end

  Admsubdevice = module_with_autoload do
    ...
  end

  Admdevice = module_with_autoload do
    ...
  end
end
```